# Why my messages in /etc/motd are not showing?

Tags: command-line, users, etc, motd, multiple-users

My welcome message is not showing, how do I check if it is enabled or disabled

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Do you have `show-motd` installed? and are using interactive shells?

Comment: I installed the latest version of Ubunto 20.4. How can I check the show-motd?

Comment: think motd is handle by pam.d, there should be an entry in /etc/pam.d/{login,sshd}

Comment: I found login, but I do not know how to modify it so that etc/motd could run.